# Is there any method i can use to stop this warning alert appearing when trying to close from different window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an application with three active windows. I display a warning alert on edit, close, and reload of a window 1.  I don't want to display this alert when logs out from a different window (such as window 3).

Comment: please give your code,then we can give the exact answer you want

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Tightened wording